# Eclipse ignores applet code

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

Trying to write and run applets in Java using Eclipse Neon. Here is a very simple example from Schildt (2012):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
/*
<applet code="SimpleApplet" width=200 height=60>
</applet>
*/
public class SimpleApplet extends Applet{

    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Simple Applet Test", 20, 60);
    }

 }
```

Now, Eclipse does start the applet, but ignores the html applet code inserted under comment. In the example above it disregards the height and width; in other examples it is indifferent to any applet parameter between /* and */. When I run the same class in Linux terminal using appletviewer , everything is fine.

In case anyone is wondering why I want to learn applets ("in 2016"), that's because Schildt said to do so first, and I trust him because his book has been quite helpful so far. Thanks in advance for bona fide help.

Comment: If you really must use Applet, what would be wrong with using an actual browser to test it?  As for Schildt, applets have been officially deprecated.   Nothing wrong with using them to learn Java; I did, 20 years ago.  But you won't see them in a real world scenario most likely.

Comment: I guess the reason for using Applet is that it's much simpler than [Hello World Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java).

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a browser.  As I said, appletviewer works, and that's even simpler than using a browser.  My question was why Eclipse cannot do it, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Run -> Run configurations... -> Java Applet -> Simple Applet`. Switch to the second tab `Parameters`. You'll see there that Width and Height are defined by default to 200. Unfortunately Eclipse ignores the comment tags while creating the configuration with defaults. You can change the values there and they will be applied regardless how you run the applet (i.e. with shortcut or from the menu).

Comment: Thanks. That is the answer. The parameter tab allows adding any other parameters with name and value, so that is the way to do it.